# List Unsubscribe in Aws-sdk nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-ses, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs

How can I add a `List-Unsubsribe : <mailto:abc@cdf.com>` header to my outgoing email message when using Amazon SES (Simple Email Service)? I am using AWS' JavaScript SDK.

Here are various documentation links I have looked at but have been unsuccessful at finding an answer: [Link1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/getting-started-nodejs.html), [Link2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/welcome.html), [Link3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk), [Link4](https://github.com/jaketrent/hello-ses/blob/master/server.js).

I've tried using both the SendMail and SendRawEmail APIs.

**Using the SendMail API**

```
let params={
 Source: auth.host, 
 Destination: { ToAddresses: [email] },
 Headers:{ListUnsubscribe :'<mailto:abc@def.com>'},  //error unexpected key Headers
 Message: {Subject:{Data: subject },Body:{Text: {Data: mail}}} 
}

ses.sendEmail(params,(err, data)=>{
    if(err){
      console.error(err);
    }else{
      console.log('Email sent: ');
      console.log(data);

    }
});
```

**Using the SendRawEmail API**

```
var mailOptions = {
      from: auth.host,
      subject: subject,
      text: mail,
      to: email,
    };

    var mail = mailcomposer(mailOptions);

    mail.build(function (err, message){
      var req = ses.sendRawEmail({RawMessage: {Data: message}});

      req.on('build', function() {
          req.httpRequest.headers["List-Unsubscribe"] = "<mailto:abc@abc.com>";
      });

      req.send(function (err, data) {
          if(err) //code
          else  //code
      });
    });
```

Comment: Can you try 'List-Unsubscribe` as your header?

Comment: Tried it. Gave error 'No such field as header or headers'

Comment: I don't think sendEmail will allow you to set headers. From the docs: The SendRawEmail API provides you the flexibility to format and send your own raw email message by specifying headers, MIME parts, and content types. SendRawEmail is typically used by advanced users. You need to provide the body of the message and all header fields that are specified as required in the Internet Message Format specification (RFC 5322). For more information, see Sending Raw Email Using the Amazon SES API.

Comment: Have you read the "also used" part of my post.....if you have then you will see i have used send raw email method there and also set headers they didnt help.

Comment: I missed that but at least now you know there's one method that definitely won't work. Upon reading further into the docs, it seems you have to specify headers inside the raw message, which seems quite inconvenient. Posting answer.

Answer (score 2):

According to the AWS docs, you can only specify custom headers using the SendRawEmail API:

> The SendRawEmail API provides you the flexibility to format and send
>   your own raw email message by specifying headers, MIME parts, and
>   content types. SendRawEmail is typically used by advanced users. You
>   need to provide the body of the message and all header fields that are
>   specified as required in the Internet Message Format specification
>   (RFC 5322). For more information, see Sending Raw Email Using the
>   Amazon SES API.

This explains why your first example doesn't work. Cool.

---

Here's why your second example, which is actually using the SendRawEmail API doesn't work.

Unfortunately, in order to specify custom headers when sending email, you have to specify them inline in the body of the raw message. There are some pretty stringent formatting requirements you must follow when crafting this raw message or your delivery could fail/output incorrectly. Although it would've been extremely helpful, there's no api method you can use that lets you use specify headers using key/value pairs.

This limitation is probably due to the fact that AWS would have to decode your base64-encoded raw message (which could be any of type Buffer, blob, typed array, string), hope you formatted your message properly, and insert your headers in the right location. This would, without doubt, be helpful for the the end user of the API, but definitely seems like a nightmare on their end with all the validation and error handling they would have to do.

Here are the detailed requirements for sending email using the SendRawEmail API:

> RawMessage — (map) The raw text of the message. The client is
>   responsible for ensuring the following:
>
> Message must contain a header and a body, separated by a blank line.
>   All required header fields must be present. Each part of a multipart
>   MIME message must be formatted properly. MIME content types must be
>   among those supported by Amazon SES. For more information, go to the
>   Amazon SES Developer Guide. Must be base64-encoded. Per RFC 5321, the
>   maximum length of each line of text, including the , must not
>   exceed 1,000 characters. Data — required — (Buffer, Typed Array, Blob,
>   String) The raw data of the message. This data needs to base64-encoded
>   if you are accessing Amazon SES directly through the HTTPS interface.
>   If you are accessing Amazon SES using an AWS SDK, the SDK takes care
>   of the base 64-encoding for you. In all cases, the client must ensure
>   that the message format complies with Internet email standards
>   regarding email header fields, MIME types, and MIME encoding.
>
> The To:, CC:, and BCC: headers in the raw message can contain a group
>   list.
>
> If you are using SendRawEmail with sending authorization, you can
>   include X-headers in the raw message to specify the "Source," "From,"
>   and "Return-Path" addresses. For more information, see the
>   documentation for SendRawEmail.
>
> Do not include these X-headers in the DKIM signature, because they are
>   removed by Amazon SES before sending the email. For more information,
>   go to the Amazon SES Developer Guide.

---

**My two cents**

This does seem highly inconvenient. I would suggest using a service like Sendgrid, which comes built-in with features such as subscription management (subscribe/unsubscribe), template management and a whole bunch of features that a modern, dedicated email service should have. However, if you don't have a choice, then maybe revel in the fact that the SendRawEmail API gives you a lot of customization, but at the expense of being a bit tedious.

You can access this information and more from the [AWS SES Javascript API docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SES.html#sendRawEmail-property):

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your second example that you are added header to the request to amazon, and not to Email itself

Please try to use following code sample:

```
var mailOptions = {
  from: auth.host,
  subject: subject,
  text: mail,
  to: email,
  headers: {
    'List-Unsubscribe': "<mailto:abc@abc.com>"
  }
};

var mail = mailcomposer(mailOptions);

mail.build(function (err, message){
  var req = ses.sendRawEmail({RawMessage: {Data: message}});

  req.send(function (err, data) {
      if(err) //code
      else  //code
  });
});
```